# Increment a date in a file

Tags: text-processing, date

I have a file with a single line of text inside. How can I modify its content without using the `vi` editor?

Below is the example:

```
PROCESS DATE =2014-08-01
```

I want to increment the `2014-08-01` date to the next possible day. My idea is creating a variable. How can I do that?

Comment: Is this on Linux or some other unix variant?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `perl`:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -pi -e 's/\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d/
 (Time::Piece->strptime($&,"%Y-%m-%d")+24*60*60)->date/ge' file
```

would increment every date in the file.

Answer (score 2):

I would write:

```
increment_date() {
    local current=$(grep -oP 'PROCESS DATE =\K.+' file)
    local next=$(date -d "$current + 1 day" +%F)
    sed -i "/PROCESS DATE =/s/$current/$next/" file
}

cat file
increment_date
cat file
increment_date
cat file
```

```
PROCESS DATE =2012-02-28
PROCESS DATE =2012-02-29
PROCESS DATE =2012-03-01
```

This assumes the PROCESS DATE line only occurs once in the file, and it is on a line by itself.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how sophisticated you need this. If all you need is to change the `01` to a `02`, you can use something like

```
sed -i 's/01/02/' file
```

or

```
perl -i -pe 's/01/02/' file
```

Or, to be on the safe side, do it only if the `01` is at the end of the line:

```
sed -i 's/01$/02/' file
perl -i -pe 's/01$/02/' file
```

Both of the above solutions will modify the original file because of the `-i` flag.

If you need to be able to take actual dates into account and, for example, increment `2014-02-28` to `2014-03-01`, you need to either use a full-fledged programming language that can parse dates or play around with the `date` command:

```
$ while IFS='=' read -r text date; do 
    echo "$text=$(date -d "$date + 1 day" +%F)"; 
  done < file > new_file
```

The above will split input lines on `=`, saving the part before the `=` as `$text` and the rest as `$date`. Then, the `$date` is fed to the `date` command which can do fancy date manipulations like add a day and then print it out in the format you want (in this case, the format is `%F` which means `Year-Month-Day`). Note that this assumes GNU date.

The `echo` command prints the contents of `$text` and then the date incremented by one day. This will fail if you have more than one `=` on any line of your file.

Answer (score 0):

My very own [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/) provide a command-line tool `dadd` which goes through a text file and adds something to every date found:

```
$ dadd -S +1d FILE
PROCESS DATE =2014-08-02
```